# Trouble animating a fadeout with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout

I'm trying to fade out some elements on a page, fetch new ones with AJAX, and then fade in the new ones.  The fade in is fine, but the fadeout just won't work.  I tried using fadeOut, because fadeIn worked fine, but the fadeout simply wouldn't work - the elements just vanished.  I'm now trying to animate an opacity change.  It works fine for the fade in.  Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout("getTestimonial()", 10000);
});

   function getTestimonial() {
     var counter = $('#products #cart-widget .counter').html();
        $('#products #cart-widget p > span').each(function(index) {
           if($(this).is('.counter')) {
           } else {
              $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 5000, function(){});
           }
        });
    $.get("testimonials_include.php5", {'counter':counter}, function(data) {
       $('#products #cart-widget p').replaceWith(data);
       $('#products #cart-widget p').children().css("opacity",0);
$('#products #cart-widget p > span').each(function(index) {
   if($(this).is('.counter')) {
   } else {
      $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 5000, function(){});
   }
});
    });
    setTimeout("getTestimonial()", 10000);
   }
```

Note that the new elements' opacity was by default 1, so I had to set them to 0 before the fade in could work.  Does anyone have any ideas why it isn't fading out?

Answer (score 1):

Ah - the problem was that the elements were being swapped before the fade could complete.  I put the entire AJAX function in the completion function for the animate method and hey presto!

Comment: That's what would have solved it. Also remember than any delay for animation's sake (fade in,fade out etc.) doesn't stop further processing, just the fade. But you have that covered with your 10 second time out.